# how to improve performance of select query

Tags: mysql

i have created on table having 45 columns and total 30000 of data in that table using mysql

I have to retrieve all data from this table but it is taking long time so i want to do some optimization. i have applied primary key and unique key want to improve the performance more .

please advise what else i can use ? below is the create and select statements

```
CREATE TABLE TISMCT 
(
    MASTER_ID         INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,             
    SLIP_NO               BIGINT UNIQUE,
    TRUCK_NO          VARCHAR(20),
    SUB_TRANSPORTER_NAME  VARCHAR(50),
    VMS_IN_WB_NO          VARCHAR(10),
    VMS_IN_WB_USER        VARCHAR(50),
    VMS_IN_DATE           DATE,
    VMS_IN_TIME           TIME,
    VMS_TARE_WEIGHT       DECIMAL(11,3),
    VMS_OUT_WB_NO         VARCHAR(10),
    VMS_OUT_WB_USER       VARCHAR(50),
    VMS_OUT_DATE          DATE,
    VMS_OUT_TIME          TIME,
    VMS_GROSS_WEIGHT      DECIMAL(11,3),
    VMS_NET_WEIGHT        DECIMAL(11,3),
    INVOICE_NO            INTEGER,
    ROYALITY_TYPE         VARCHAR(10),
    ROYALTY_PASS_NO       VARCHAR(50),
    EXCISE_AMOUNT         DECIMAL(11,3),
    EDU_CESS_AMOUNT       DECIMAL(11,3),
    HSECESS_AMOUNT        DECIMAL(11,3),
    CLEAN_ENG_CESS_AMOUNT DECIMAL(11,3),
    ROYALTY_AMOUNT       DECIMAL(11,3), 
    BAL_ROYALTY_AMOUNT   DECIMAL(20,3),
    VS_IN_WB_NO           VARCHAR(10),
    VS_IN_WB_USER         VARCHAR(50),
    VS_IN_DATE            DATE,
    VS_IN_TIME            TIME,
    VS_GROSS_WEIGHT       DECIMAL(11,3),
    VS_OUT_WB_NO          VARCHAR(10),
    VS_OUT_WB_USER        VARCHAR(50),
    VS_OUT_DATE       DATE,
    VS_OUT_TIME       TIME,
    VS_TARE_WEIGHT        DECIMAL(11,3),
    VS_NET_WEIGHT         DECIMAL(11,3),
    DUMP_LOCATION         VARCHAR(50),
    IS_BILLED         CHAR(1),
    IS_ACTIVE         CHAR(1),
    CREATED_DT        DATE,
    MODIFY_DT         DATE,
    CREATED_BY            VARCHAR(50),
    MODIFY_BY             VARCHAR(50),
    EXTRA_FIELD1          VARCHAR(50),
    EXTRA_FIELD2          VARCHAR(50),
    EXTRA_FIELD3          VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Query

```
SELECT 
  MASTER_ID,
  SLIP_NO,
  TRUCK_NO,
  SUB_TRANSPORTER_NAME,
  VMS_IN_WB_NO,
  VMS_IN_WB_USER,
  VMS_IN_DATE,
  VMS_IN_TIME,
  VMS_TARE_WEIGHT,
  VMS_OUT_WB_NO,
  VMS_OUT_WB_USER,
  VMS_OUT_DATE,
  VMS_OUT_TIME,
  VMS_GROSS_WEIGHT,
  VMS_NET_WEIGHT,
  INVOICE_NO,
  ROYALITY_TYPE,
  ROYALTY_PASS_NO,
  EDU_CESS_AMOUNT,
  HSECESS_AMOUNT,
  CLEAN_ENG_CESS_AMOUNT,
  ROYALTY_AMOUNT,
  BAL_ROYALTY_AMOUNT,
  VS_IN_WB_NO,
  VS_IN_WB_USER,
  VS_IN_DATE,
  VS_IN_TIME,
  VS_GROSS_WEIGHT,
  VS_OUT_WB_NO,
  VS_OUT_WB_USER,
  VS_OUT_DATE,
  VS_OUT_TIME,
  VS_TARE_WEIGHT,
  VS_NET_WEIGHT,
  DUMP_LOCATION,
  IS_BILLED,
  IS_ACTIVE,
  CREATED_DT,
  MODIFY_DT,
  CREATED_BY,
  MODIFY_BY,
  EXTRA_FIELD1,
  EXTRA_FIELD2,
  EXTRA_FIELD3 
FROM
  TISMCT 
WHERE IS_BILLED = 'Y' 
  AND IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' 
ORDER BY CREATED_DT DESC ;
```

Comment: Index is billed, is active and created dt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the select itself you can specify some condition. Do you really want to retrieve all the data or latest one or oldest one. According to your requirement you can modify your query.

If you want latest data based on date column, for example:

```
Select top 1000 
    column1, colunm2,...... 
From 
    table 
Order By 
    date Desc
```

This will retrieve the latest 1000 records.

If you want oldest data based on date column

```
Select top 1000 column1, colunm2,...... 
from table 
order by date asc
```

This will return the oldest 1000 records.

(or)
put where condition

```
Select top 1000 column1, colunm2,...... 
from table 
where column = 1234 
order by date asc
```

Be specific in your needs and optimize query accordingly.

Comment: i tried that one still have one question in mind which value we have to consider is output duration or the fetch Time                                      Time   Action    Message                   Duration / Fetch
3 1 17:30:37 select * from TISMCT_test LIMIT 11000 11000 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.328 sec

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really need EVERY thing from the table and every recordset, then there is not much you can do about it. It's not like mysql has to search things first, it's just that you want all data and the Server takes his time to send it to you.

For what reason do you need ALL the data? Maybe you could overthink that part.

Comment: user are uploading the data from excel to database so we kept one table to upload excel data also we need to display all data in front end for latest 5000 record